# Display google navigation based on given locations

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, cocoa-touch

I am working on google maps integration I am trying to display google navigation at present I am using the following code. I am trying to display like google navigation based on location what I pass through the api

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&alternateroutes=false&sensor=true" ,12.920631,77.670494,8.3075,77.2218]];
NSURLResponse *res;
NSError *err;NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&alternateroutes=false&sensor=true" ,12.920631,77.670494,8.3075,77.2218]];
NSURLResponse *res;
NSError *err;

NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] returningResponse:&res error:&err];
if(data)
{
    NSDictionary *dic=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    if(dic)
    {
            NSArray *routes=dic[@"routes"];
            NSArray *legs=routes[0][@"legs"];
            NSArray *steps=legs[0][@"steps"];
            NSLog(@"the legs are:%@",steps);
            NSMutableArray *textsteps=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray *latlong=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for(int i=0; i< [steps count]; i++){
                NSString *html=steps[i][@"html_instructions"];
                [latlong addObject:steps[i][@"end_location"]];
                NSLog(@"the data:%@",steps[i][@"end_location"]);
                [textsteps addObject:html];
                encodedPath    = [[[steps objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"polyline"] valueForKey:@"points"];
                [self polylineWithEncodedString:encodedPath];

                polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
                polyline.strokeWidth = 2.f;
                polyline.map = mapView;
                NSLog(@"the encoded patg:%@",encodedPath);                    

                GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
                marker1.map = mapView;                    
                NSLog(@"Direction path");  
}


}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Connection Error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

I am expecting an output like 
[image]

Comment: That's not a question. What's your question? "How do I do it" is way too broad for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping you are expecting like this code

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:  
[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"]];
} else {
 NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps://");
}
```

Comment: Yeah this code is navigating me to google app what I want is like the same action should perform but it should not navigate to other app

Answer (score 2):

You want to show same direction, time and everything as Google Maps do. **Google Maps SDK** of iOS will draw a path for you on maps.

You can use the [Google Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to get and request for direction between source and destination. You can use [GMSPolyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_polyline) to draw it.

But other things, like where to take a turn, whats time is left to reach the destination and other things, you need to manage manually. If you want to show same as Google, **you need to make URL and open in WebView**.

You can see [URLSchema](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme) documentation for more detail.

Comment: But how we can change the poly line colour based on traffic. In google api response we get traffic status but how we will update the same in poly line. Also If I open url in web view we cannot customise the annotation

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro checkout this link, if you are want to handle manually. But you go with URL or open in Google Map app, then you don't need to worry.